# Apply Aero style on WPF library

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I want to force the Aero style on my forms. I created a "WPF Class Library" and added a form and controls to this form. As the library will be called by 3rd party C# applications running on different OS, I want to force to always apply the Aero style.

But as it is a WPF class library I have no `App.xaml` file where I could put my Resource Dictionary.
I placed it in a dedicated custom `Styles.xaml` therefore and in my form I reference it like

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml">
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

where Styles.xaml looks like

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyLib">
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero;V4.0.0.0;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

and is set to "`Build action: Embedded resource`" and is stored in the main project folder. I also added a reference to `PresentationFramework.Aero` in my project.

When I call my library form from the C# application,  I get an error saying

**Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.' Line number 'x' and line position 'y'**

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The Build Action of a ResourceDictionary should be set to Page and nothing else.

Comment: I changed it to Page but I still get the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/PresentationFramework.Aero;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml" />
```

Refere this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(VS.85).aspx) article for more details.

**UPDATE**

Include ResourceDictionary in PCL

Create a ResourceDictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/PresentationFramework.Aero;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>

  <!-- store here your styles -->

</ResourceDictionary>
```

You can use it from Your PCL in WPF App

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Window"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window"
        Height="300"
        Width="300">

  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Your.Base.AssemblyName;component/YourResDictionaryFolder/Dictionary1.xaml" />
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>

  </Grid>
</Window>
```

`Your.Base.AssemblyName` =  Dll name

`YourResDictionaryFolder` = Folder where you created your ResourceDictionary

`Dictionary1.xaml` =  File name which you created above

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve my problem. The error still appears

Comment: Please check for the duplicate keynames in your app and resourceDictionary xaml file.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by that? If I understood you correctly I just have to insert line you sent into my "Styles.xaml" right?

Comment: No you need to add this line to you app.xaml file. Under Resource dictionary mapping. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: As I wrote in my initial post I have no app.xaml file because it is a WPF class library